# Accessible HTML structure for syntax highlighter

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm fixing an old WordPress syntax highlighter plugin (the plugin owner abandoned it), and while fixing the PHP errors was easy, while I'm fixing it, I might as well improve accessibility as well.

My question is regarding the HTML structure for the code. I want to show the number on one side and the code next to it:

[image]

I figured the HTML would be something like this:

```
<section> <!-- Maybe article? -->
    <header>
        <h1>Sample HTML</h1> <!-- Maybe <h3> would fit my blog posts best -->
        <div role="toolbar">toolabar buttons here</div>
    </header>
    <ol>
        <li><span class="sh-r ">&lt;div </span><span class="sh-e ">class</span>=<span class="sh-s ">"grid"</span><span class="sh-r ">&gt;</span>
        ...
    </ol>
</section>
```

But I'm not sure. Should the code be in an `<ol>` or a `<table>`? Are the spans for changing the color ok? Is the toolbar role appropriate? Am I missing something? If anyone has an example of an accessible code highlighter, I'd love to see it.

The way it is right now, it's a table with all numbers in one `<td>` and all the code in another!

Comment: What you show in the screenshot, is that an editing area with line numbers or just a source code view that can only be inspected?

Comment: @Tsundoku It’s not editable, it’s just to show the code.

Comment: I'll need to check how a screen reader renders the source code view in a web browser and then determine what sort of HTML code achieves the most similar effect. Right now, I'm inclined to use just [`pre` and `code`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#example-8bacfdd1) and avoid both `ol` and (especially) `table`.

Comment: @Tsundoku I agree, but how would the line number be represented?

Comment: If you "inspect" a "view source" on a page you will see it is indeed a table with 2 columns, left column line number and right column HTML with `<span>`s for syntax highlighting. There is some merit to the `<ol>` idea but you would have to try it with a screen reader to see if it is any easier to use.  **Obviously to cover the last point you made** the table is indeed a table with each row number and line of code in a separate `<tr>`, as it stands it looks like the used the table for presentation in the plugin which is obviously a big no no!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the code be in an `<ol>` or a `<table>`?

I would say that `<ol>` is more appropriate than `<table>`.

Using a table here looks a bit like presentational purpose only. I wouldn't call a table with line numbers on the left and code lines on the right exactly a data table.

> Are the spans for changing the color ok?

As as default and because you can't do better in HTML anyway, I would say yes, it's fine.

IF HTML has more specific elements to semantically indicate keywords, blocks, numbers, strings, variables, etc. then you would be strongly recommanded to use them instead of spans.
But there aren't really such specific elements, except maybe `<var`, `<kbd>` and/or `<samp>`; but their semantic signification has never been very clear.

However, as a higher level, you should be using `<code>` or `<pre>` to enclose the whole code, to mark it as such.
The problem is that, if you use those two elements, you can no longer use `<ol>` or `<table>`.

Perhaps the most acceptable compromise would be `<ol><li><code>One line of code</code></li>...</ol>`.

In any case, for specific things like marking keywords inside the line of code, you don't have another better choice than `<span>` in what HTML has to offer.

> Is the toolbar role appropriate?

Given that you haven't given the code inside the div, it's a bit difficult to answer.

Normally, a toolbar should contain a set of buttons or occasionally other controls like dropdown menus, and in principle nothig else then that.

If the content of that div corresponds to this simple definition, yes, the toolbar is appropriate. Otherwise, no.

Not that it isn't very worth it to use the toolbar role for less than 3 buttons

As I can imagine here, this div contains only a single button to copy the code in clipboard. If it's indeed the case, then by the definition above, it isn't very appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. For the record, the toolbar would have 5 buttons for different actions.